# What's wrong with this code? Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type

Tags: c#

I'm writing a small console app. I have no idea what's wrong...

```
namespace Mtrx
{
    class Mtrx
    {
        private double[,] _sqMtrx;
        private double _mtrxSize { get; set; }

        public Mtrx(int i)
        {

            if (i <= 0)
                throw new FormatException();
            else
                this._sqMtrx = new double[i, i];
            _mtrxSize = i;
        }

        public static Mtrx operator +(Mtrx m1, Mtrx m2)
        {
            if (m1._mtrxSize == m2._mtrxSize)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= m1._mtrxSize; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j <= m1._mtrxSize; j++)
                    {
                        return m1[i, j] == m1[i, j] + m2[i, j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I get:
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Mtrx.Mtrx'

Comment: Side note you `Matrix` class seem to be missing some letters... nt sr wh d tht.

Comment: Do not name your class the same as its namespace. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well yes, the problem is here:

```
return m1[i, j] == m1[i, j] + m2[i, j];
```

This is wrong in all kinds of ways:

- You're trying to return a `bool` when the operator is meant to return a `Mtrx` (horrible name, by the way - embrace vowels!)
- You're trying to use an indexer on `m1` and `m2`, which are variables of type `Mtrx`. You haven't created an indexer. You *either* need to use `m1._sqMtrx[i, j]` etc, or you need to declare an indexer, such as:

  ```
  public double this[int i, int j]
  {
      return _sqMtrx[i, j];
  }
  ```
- Your method doesn't return anything if the two arguments have different sizes

Fundamentally I think you should think again about the whole operator.

Comment: An Add method that accepts another `Mtrx` object would probably be better, or at least easier to understand.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: No, as that would presumably mutate the existing matrix. (Or it would be badly named - like a lot of methods in the BCL.) It's cleaner to have an operator which creates a new matrix, IMO - but the OP needs to revisit the code significantly in order to achieve that.

Comment: Well, make it a `static` method, pass in the two `Mtrx` objects, and return an added `Mtrx`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Okay... and at that point why is it better to be a method than an operator? Fundamentally the fact that it's an operator is the *least* problematic bit of this code. Even the choice of namespace name is worse than that decision, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet Deck chairs on the titanic then?

Comment: @asawyer: In this case, deck chairs which seem reasonably laid out to me already :)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access your object like an array, instead of accessing array inside your object. try `m1._sqMatrix[i,j]`

Comment: @RobertHarvey: That's not a problem - the code is within the same class.

Comment: Yes, but you're dereferencing a passed-in matrix object, not accessing the internal members.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: So? It's perfectly valid C#. Visibility in C# is defined by where code is able to access members - any code declared within the body of the `Mtrx` class can use any private members of `Mtrx` on *any* instance.

Comment: You mean you can access the private member of a passed in object, so long as it's the same class definition you're in?  That sounds messed up.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It's the way both Java and C# work, and always have. It's entirely reasonable IMO. (All kinds of things would be much harder otherwise - or implementation details would have to be leaked for no good reason.)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the innermost line in your nested for loops be referencing the array, not the mr1, mr2 variables?

```
    public static Mtrx operator +(Mtrx m1, Mtrx m2)
    {
        if (m1._mtrxSize == m2._mtrxSize)
        {
            var outVal = new Mtrx(m1._mtrxSize)

            for (int i = 1; i <= m1._mtrxSize; i++)
                for (int j = 1; j <= m1._mtrxSize; j++)
                    outVal._sqMtrx[i,j] = m1._sqMtrx[i, j] + m2._sqMtrx[i, j];

            return outVal;
        }
    }
```

If you want to use indexing syntax on the class itself, then you must add an indexer....

```
class Mtrx
{
    private double[,] _sqMtrx;
    private int _mtrxSize { get; set; }

    public Mtrx(int i)
    {

        if (i <= 0)
            throw new FormatException();
        else
            this._sqMtrx = new double[i, i];
        _mtrxSize = i;
    }

    public double this[int i, int j]
    {  
        get { return _sqMtrx[i, j]; }
        set { _sqMtrx[i, j] = value; }
    }

    public static Mtrx operator +(Mtrx m1, Mtrx m2)
    {
        if (m1._mtrxSize == m2._mtrxSize)
        {
            var outVal = new Mtrx(m1._mtrxSize)

            for (int i = 1; i <= m1._mtrxSize; i++)
                for (int j = 1; j <= m1._mtrxSize; j++)
                    outVal[i,j] = m1[i, j] + m2[i, j];

            return outVal;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get: The best overloaded method match for 'Mtrxy.Mtrx.Mtrx(int)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: your variabhle _mtrxSize  should be an int not a doubkle.